# Greyish/Dull colour after Render even after using sRGB

Tags: eevee-render-engine

I am new to Blender and was using it for creating YT Channel Intro with templates available on Velosofy (This one: https://www.velosofy.com/template/intramazing-2d-text-intro-free-professional-intro-zxbyijehap4).

The problem is after rendering it with FFmpeg (I even tried AVI JPEg) and H.264 it doesn't render it as in preview, it becomes dull and even the object have black spots on their edges.

[image: Preview window]

[image: After Rendering]

In the Render Properties>Colour Management the value for Display device is sRGB, view transform is Standard and sequences is sRGB still it's the same...
And yes it's a video and for trying O rendered image...

Comment: you might want to switch your preview mode to "render" (last circular icon in the bottom-right), it won't change the result but would give you a better idea of what to expect

Comment: Yeah I did it and I adjusted the Gamma and exposure in the render preview mode and matched it to material view and solved the problem. But why is that dullness even after using sRGB?

Comment: i think the difference is that material view doesn't take lights into account, so like, everything is as if it was fully lit up and without shadows

Comment: Yeah that must be the reason...